# Get filepath from glob-entry for use in fs::read_to_string

Tags: rust, glob

I read a directory with glob. I can print the filepath but im unable to  get the path as a string to use it in `fs::read_to_string()`

```rust
extern crate glob;

use glob::glob;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let source_files_glob = "/my/sample/path/*.ext";

    for entry in glob(source_files_glob).expect("Failed to read glob pattern") {
        println!("{}", entry.unwrap().display());

        let file_content = fs::read_to_string(entry.unwrap().display()).expect("Something went wrong reading the file");

        println!("Content: {}", file_content);
    }
}
```

I got this error:

```
  --> src/main.rs:12:28
   |
12 |         let file_content = fs::read_to_string(entry.unwrap().display()).expect("Something went wrong reading the file");
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::AsRef<std::path::Path>` is not implemented for `std::path::Display<'_>`
   |
```

How can I get the full filepath from entry to use it in "fs::read_to_string" ?

Comment: Why this `display()` in `read_to_string(entry.unwrap().display())` ? Bad copy-paste ?

Comment: It was only my last try. read_to_string(entry) doesnt work also:
```rust
12 |         let file_content = fs::read_to_string(entry).expect("Something went wrong reading the file");
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::AsRef<std::path::Path>` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<std::path::PathBuf, glob::GlobError>`
```

Comment: Just remove the `display()`: `fs::read_to_string(entry.unwrap())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a string as [`std::fs::read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_to_string.html) takes a `AsRef<Path>` as argument.

You should simply use the entry's `OK` value, which is a `Path`:

```
let file_content = fs::read_to_string(entry.unwrap()).expect("...");
```

Note that a clean program would usually handle errors:

```
for entry in glob(source_files_glob).expect("Failed to read glob pattern") {
    match entry {
        OK(path) => {
            println!("{}", path.display());
            let file_content = fs::read_to_string(path).expect("...");
            println!("Content: {}", file_content);
        }
        Err(e) => {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand this in the docs: ```if let Ok(path) = entry {
        println!("{:?}", path.display())
    }
```

Yes, a clean program. I just tried a little bit on how to do that and then shortened it as an example for here. First of all I wanted it to work at all.